# Converting a custom date format (string) to a datetime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, .net-4.0

I have a large set (100+ million) of observations with the date represented as a custom string format. We did not generate the date strings, I just need to convert the date string to a datetime type.

How do I convert a string date (eg, 12 JUN 2010) to a datetime? My thoughts are to parse the string into components, assemble them in the correct order, and pass that string to the constructor of datetime. Is there a way to pass datetime() a custom date format string instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Take a look at [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ee1y0t7.aspx), e.g.

```
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(
    "12 JUN 2010", 
    "dd MMM yyyy", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You can also specify a fourth parameter to set the [Kind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.kind.aspx) of date/time, for example if they are UTC date/times then you'd likely want to specify `DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx), and pass the format into this method using the [custom date and time format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).  This will allow you to parse the date in one pass.

Answer (score 0):

That DateTime string is valid for `DateTime.Parse()` (or `.TryParse()`)

As for a truly custom string that .Parse() can't handle, you are probably correct, you'd need to pull your string apart and reassemble it in a useful manner.