# Convert string yyyy/mm/dd/hh/mm to datetime in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello I want to convert string to DateTime.
My string is like this '2016/11/18/12/03'.2016 is year,11 is month 18 is a day 12 hour and 3 min. I want to convert it into format like this '2016-11-18 12:03:00.000'. How can do that in C#? Can I use split function which form array. That split yyyy, month, date, hh and min. How to add them to form new date?

```
string s = '2016/11/18/12/03'
string[] arr = s.split('/');
```

Comment: Lookup DateTime.ParseExact https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx and Custom Date Format String https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3373348/993547).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the below should work -

```
using System.Globalization;

DateTime result;
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
string dateString = "yyyy/MM/dd/HH/mm";
result = DateTime.ParseExact("2016/11/18/12/03", dateString, provider);
//2016-11-18 12:03:00.000
string display = result.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use DateTime.ParseExact to turn the string into a DateTime and then turn it into a string by calling dteTime.ToString passing the required output format.

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(myString, "yyyy/MM/dd/HH/mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string output = dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply,u have missed third para of DateTime.PaerseExact()

Comment: @JuiTest - Thanks, adjusted

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = "2016/11/18/12/03"

DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "yyyy/MM/dd/HH/mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

string s2 = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
```